# Disable Radio Button once selected?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have two radio buttons on my current page and need to disable the one that is selected so that it cannot be selected a second time. Can I add something before the break to disable the button.

```
switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.radioButton:
                if(checked)
                    txt.setText(kmToM(dist));

                break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                if(checked)
                    txt.setText(mToK(dist));
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Which event are you using? Because if a radiobutton is already selected, and the same one is selected again, your event shouldn't be being triggered.

Comment: can you include your `html` markup for the `radio buttons`?

Comment: The button is triggering again. I am not using any hrml, just an xml.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
$(YOUR_RADIO).attr("disabled","disabled");
```